# Calculate $E[a^N]$ for Poisson random variable $N$

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

> Calculate $E[a^N]$ for a Poisson random variable $N$ with parameter $\lambda \cdot T$, where $a>0$ is a constant independent of $N$.

My answer:

\begin{align}
E[a^N] &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n}{n!} a ^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda T}(a\lambda T)^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda T} e^{a\lambda T}\frac{e^{-a\lambda T}(a\lambda T)^n}{n!} \\
       &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {e^{-\lambda T(1-a)}} \frac{e^{-a\lambda T}(a \lambda T)^n}{n!}\\
       &= {e^{-\lambda T(1-a)}}  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a\lambda T}(a \lambda T)^n}{n!}\\
       &= {e^{-\lambda T(1-a)}}\\
\end{align}

Is this right?

Comment: What you write after your initial sentence suggests that $a$ is the name of the random variable. You could have written "Calculate $\operatorname{E}(a^n)$ for a Poisson random variable $a$". Also you shouldn't be using the same symbol, $a,$ to refer to two different things: the random variable itself and any of its possible values. Also, note that if $a$ is a Poisson-distributed random variable then you don't have $a>0$ with probability $1,$ although you do have $a\ge0.$

Comment: Indeed the 'Calculate..." sentence of your post is quite messed up. Could you streamline it?

Comment: @Did I edited and clarified the statement.

Comment: @Did Is that clear now?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is that clear now?

Comment: This is correct now. I'm not sure whether it was before since I didn't entirely follow what was done. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  In general, if $X$ is a random variable (typically a discrete random variable) then $\mathbb{E}[z^X]$ is referred to as the probability generating function (PGF for short) of $X$.  Your answer for the Poisson random variable of mean $\lambda T$ is correct, as can be verified [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E} \Big[a^N\Big] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n}{n!} a^n \\[10pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda T(1-a)} \frac{e^{-a\lambda T}(a \lambda T)^n}{n!} \longleftarrow \text{I'm not sure what you did here.}
\end{align}

I would do this:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E} \Big[a^N\Big] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n}{n!} a^n \\[10pt]
&= e^{-\lambda T} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!} a^n & \longleftarrow & \text{ This can be done because $e^{-\lambda T}$ does not} \\
& & & \text{ change as $n$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.} \\[10pt]
& = e^{-\lambda T} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a\lambda T)^n}{n!} \\[10pt]
& = e^{-\lambda T} e^{a\lambda T} = e^{-\lambda T(1-a)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Please see my answer. I added a few more steps to clarify what I have done in that step.